# Using value of a variable as a property name

Tags: php

I've got the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    $bar1 = 'a';
    $bar2 = 'b'

    public function Update($updateInfo)
    {
        $this->$updateInfo['property'] = $updateInfo[$updateInfo['property']];
    }
}
```

In my code, I've created a Foo object:

```
$objFoo = new Foo();
```

Now, I want to be able to update either of the properties, without the update function knowing which. The array would look like this:

```
$updateInfo['bar1'] = 'newVal';
$updateInfo['property'] = 'bar1';
```

I remember hearing or reading that something like this is possible in PHP, but I'm currently getting the error:

> Object of class could not be converted to string

Am I mistaken in thinking this can be done? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: what's the version of php this is running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put braces around the value being used as the property:

```
$this->{$updateInfo['property']} = $updateInfo[$updateInfo['property']];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew I wasn't dreaming this.

Answer (score 4):

You must be using PHP 7+. This is because of a backwards incompatible change in the [handling of indirect variables, properties, and methods](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect). In PHP 5, your [code works](https://3v4l.org/sI3AE) as is because it's being interpreted as

```
$this->{$updateInfo['property']} = $updateInfo[$updateInfo['property']];
```

which is your intended behavior. However, in PHP 7+ it's interpreted as

```
($this->$updateInfo)['property'] = $updateInfo[$updateInfo['property']];
```

so it gives you the error you're getting.

Make the behavior you want explicit and it will work fine in both versions:

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar1 = 'a';
    private $bar2 = 'b';

    public function Update($updateInfo)
    {
        $this->{$updateInfo['property']} = $updateInfo[$updateInfo['property']];
    }
}

$objFoo = new Foo();

$updateInfo['bar1'] = 'newVal';
$updateInfo['property'] = 'bar1';
$objFoo->Update($updateInfo);
var_dump($objFoo);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vth8N)